# my page load time is so slow after the code

Tags: php

I have these two lines of code:

```php
<?php $arr2 = explode(' ',trim($Event["League"]["name"]));$LeagueName1 = $arr2[0]; ?>
```

and

```php
<img class="league-name" src="/theme/Design/img/leagues/<?php 
if(isset($LeagueName1)):?><?=$LeagueName1;?><?php endif; ?>.png" 
alt="" /></img>
```

After I wrote them, my page loading time is slow. Also, I get  bad gateway error when I upload a new **png** file to the **src** directory.

Comment: Image tags are self-closing. Get rid of the `</img>` closing tag. If you have a "massive page loading", it's probably your site trying to return a 404 Not Found response. If you want to avoid that, use an if/else to display a default image if the league doesn't have a valid image.

Comment: thanks for the cm , can you please tell me where can i add the if else ? cuz i tried once and the default image didnt show up , i tried like this 

....<?=$LeagueName1;?><?php else: ?>default<?php endif; ?>.png" alt="" /></img>

Comment: I would do it like this  `<?= isset($LeagueName1) ? $LeagueName1 :  $defaultImage; ?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would clean this up and add a default "fallback" image as others have said in the comments

```
<img class="league-name" src="/theme/Design/img/leagues/<?= isset($LeagueName1) ? $LeagueName1 : $defaultImage; ?>.png" />
```

Alternately you could check first and then to the output

```
<?php 
    $image_src = isset($LeagueName1) ? $LeagueName1 : $defaultImage; 
?> 

//... other stuff

<img class="league-name" src="/theme/Design/img/leagues/<?= $image_src; ?>.png" />
```

Without the default image you wind up trying to load this file

```
  /theme/Design/img/leagues/.png
```

Which probably does not exist.  You can even omit the image altogether

```
  <?php if(!empty($LeagueName1)): ?>
       <img class="league-name" src="/theme/Design/img/leagues/<?= $LeagueName1; ?>.png" />
  <?php endif; ?>
```

That all depends on what you want to do...

If you notice I changed this to `empty`.  Empty doesn't care if it's set or not, but it will save you in the case that `$LeagueName1 = ''` which is set, but would put you right back where you started.  Just don't use `0` for the file name such as `0.png` .. lol

Comment: thanks for answer , i followed everything you said but they cant load the default image , now  they just show the browser's broken image icon **and** i dont know why they loads one by one and im sure the load time is about that , there is no empty name they all has a name , i just need to upload the png for them then they apear , but there is alot of names and every day they updates , so i can not handle all of them in a day , and my users would be not happy for the loading time

Comment: How large are the image files, are you setting them to a smaller size. If so you may want to think about saving thumbnail images.

Comment: they are less than 1kb

Comment: I'm sorry but your comment is very ambiguous,  `they cant load the default image`, `now they just show the browser's broken image`,`they loads one by one`, `there is no empty name they all has a name`, `i just need to upload the png for them`

Comment: What name, the src attribute?  Why wont the default image load, what PNG do you need to upload, the default one, or ?.  None of that really makes sense.  Forget everything you know about what you are doing, and re-read that.  `they` `them` `these` etc.

Comment: i  used  this  `$defaultImage = "/theme/Design/img/leagues/default.png";`

 for   default   image  and   i   dont   know   why   they  wont   load ,  the    code    that  wrote   picking   up   the   first   word   of   the   league   name   then   if   there   is   a   png   in   src    with   same   name   as  `$LeagueName1`   then   it  shows   up   that  png   front   of   the  league  name

Comment: i just sorted out with uploading all the needed png files , thank you so much any way